# Ideas behind theorems and proofs

Tags: discussion

I do not know if anyone has asked this type of question/s before or not.

Most of the time new structures and results in mathematics are being taught without giving any reason or motivation for such a definition or result.

Proofs in any branch of mathematics(Differential Equation in my case) are often full of crazy constructions and clever arguments.

I am sure there is some idea behind every trick, result and definition, sometimes I figure out by myself. Otherwise there is no option, but remember it.

I ask experienced people what is good source of getting ideas, not results without any motivation.

Answer (score 3):

The core of your problem, which I read as:

> How to gain intuition for proofs and theorems in the area of differential equations?

can be a good question for the main site. However, it's still a bit too broad -- differential equations is a large area of mathematics, so any questions you would like to ask about it on MSE should be more focussed than that.

For example, you can check for questions asking for "intuitive" differential equations books (if they don't exist already, you can ask a new one, but probably there are some already there). In general, questions about the intuition behind *specific* things you run into will be well-received.